# Types of property 'target' are incompatible

Tags: typescript

Event is:

> The Event interface represents an event which takes place in the DOM. ...

```
export interface MyEvent<T = EventTarget> extends Event {
  readonly target: T | null;
}
```

Error:

> Interface 'MyEvent' incorrectly extends interface 'Event'.
> Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
> Type 'T | null' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget | null'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget | null'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget'.

Why can't I do this?

[Play..](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BRAN2BQB4AVOAXjjIpmsygHNgYA%20OUVJABMAzo3Io4AbwBQcOFGCZBEJABtCcGG04wAXHFoAfOEgCuq1QG5pAXyA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `T = EventTarget` to `T extends EventTarget`

Try this one:

```
export interface MyEvent<T extends EventTarget> extends Event {
  readonly target: T | null;
}
```

If you sure T is `EventTarget` you don't need to `T`. simply use this one:

```
export interface MyEvent extends Event {
  readonly target: EventTarget | null;
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BRAN2BQB4AVOUVJAEwGc4yKZrMoBzYGAHx0QDFm3Io4AbwBQcOFGCZGEJABtCcGNz4wAXHFoAfOEgCuatQG4ZAXyA)

Comment: Why? Why so, I don't want to inherit?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси Ok why do you need T? use this: `export interface MyEvent extends Event {
  readonly target: EventTarget | null;
}`

Comment: There may be different types. And they don't have to inherit from EventTarget. This is bad?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси It doesn't have meaning. when it is other type you can't use as `EventTarget` unless you extend it

Comment: Why `It doesn't meaning`?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси You know you are extendig the `Event` and it has a property `target` that is in `EventTarget` type. So you can't define `target` in any other type you want. right? unless you extend the `EventTarget`